# How to annotated a record for jackson-dataype-hal

Tags: java, clojure, jackson

I've try to replicate the examples on https://github.com/openapi-tools/jackson-dataformat-hal#usage with Clojure, but the output of the serialization is not the expected one.

The annotated record is serialized as plain map and not as hal structure.

This is  the namespace, reduced to the problem.

```clj
(ns hal
  (:gen-class)
  (:import (io.openapitools.jackson.dataformat.hal.annotation
            Curie
            Link
            Resource
            EmbeddedResource)
           (io.openapitools.jackson.dataformat.hal
            HALMapper
            HALLink
            HALLink$Builder)))

(defn hal-link
  [url]
  (.build (HALLink$Builder. url)))

(defrecord ^{Resource true} AssociatedModel
    [^String AssociatedProperty
     ^{Link true :tag HALLink} self])

(defrecord ^{Resource true} Model
    [^String modelProperty
     ^{Link true :tag HALLink} self
     ^{Link {:rel "associated"} :tag HALLink} relation
     ^{EmbeddedResource true :tag AssociatedModel} associated])


(def model (->Model
            "Test"
            (hal-link "/api/model/1" )
            (hal-link "/api/assoc/1" )
            (->AssociatedModel
             "AssociatedModel"
             (hal-link "/api/assoc/1" ))))

(def hal-mapper (HALMapper.))

(.writeValueAsString hal-mapper model)
```

Expected result:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": { "href": "https://..."},
        "rel:associated": { "href": "https://..."}
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "associated": {
            "_links": {
                "self": { "href": "https://..." }
            },
            "associatedProperty": "..."
        }
    },
```

Actual result:

```
{
  ":self": {
    "href": "/api/model/1",
    "templated": false
  },
  ":associated": {
    ":AssociatedProperty": "AssociatedModel",
    ":self": {
      "href": "/api/assoc/1",
      "templated": false
    }
  },
  ":relation": {
    "href": "/api/assoc/1",
    "templated": false
  },
  ":modelProperty": "Test"
}
```

Comment: At first sight, everything looks correct. One thing I noticed that you annotate Associated with EmbeddedResource instead of Embedded as in your reference.
Do you mind posting either deps.edn so I can launch it on my machine or check if you have proper annotations assigned using commands at the end of this section: https://clojure.org/reference/datatypes#_java_annotation_support